# Simple Regex problem that I just CAN'T figure out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, string

I have quite a simple problem, I need to parse through this string:

```
"user_id" => "BXoVWYg-T_QS"
```

And grab only the `BXoVWYg-T_QS`

I have used regex thus far to grab that much from a much larger string, but I can't figure out how to get it down to just the contents of the user_id string

This is the regex I have so far:

```
"user_id" => ".*"
```

Please help!

**Update** I have a string of html that I am trying to parse through for an iPhone app in objective-c. If I can just get the regex syntax down, my problems will be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"user_id" => "([^"]*)"
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but it looks as though that regex is just returning the original string "user_id" => "BXoVWYg-T_QS"...I am just looking to get what is inside of the second set of ""

Comment: @Jim — The problem isn't the regex, but how you're using it.  Check your regex API's documentation for how to access the "captured groups" or "subpatterns" in the result.  You will *always* match the entire string; groups are how you access specific bits of it.  (In this case, you want group 1.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate your capture using parens like this:

```
"user_id" => "(.*)"
```

You can then locate that match. Are you using JavaScript, Perl, C#, ???

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.*` is greedy -- so it grabs everything up to the **last** available `"` in your line / string (depending on the mode you are using).

What you need is to either:

A) Make the regex non-greedy.  `.*?` will do that in some platforms.
B) Specifically exclude `"` from the list of characters you'd like to match:
    `"user_id" => "([^"]*)"` is what you'll want then.